# How to merge two pandas df, if one df is different levels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to pivot a df and merge. This code was working fine in pandas 1.5, but in pandas 2.0, i am getting an error

> MergeError: Not allowed to merge between different levels. (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)

Here is my code:

```
pivotdf = pd.pivot_table(df, values = ["col5",'col6'], index=['date'], columns = 'Sector')
df = pd.merge(df,pivotdf ,on=["date"],how="left",suffixes=["","_bySector_pivot"])
```

Comment: can you give a small dataset example for which you get the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.